# Is is possible to use KDE as well as Gnome on a machine?

Tags: gnome, kde

Is it possible to install KDE and Gnome on your machine (using Fedora) in such a way that when you boot, you can specify whether you want to use KDE or Gnome.

Even better would be if you can switch between the two without having to reboot. I think it should be possible. How can I do this?

Answer (score 11):

It's perfectly possible. Just install both KDE and Gnome using your package manager. You will then be able to choose which desktop you want in the login screen using the "Sessions" menu.

You'll be able to switch between the desktops by logging out and then choosing the other one in the login screen. So no reboot is required.

Comment: Just as a note, you'll still have to choose between gdm, kdm, or at your discretion another login manager, but that doesn't affect which DE/WM you login to.

Comment: The sessions menu typically doesn't appear until you enter (or select) your user name, but before you enter your password.

Answer (score 3):

You can install as many desktop environments as you want, switch between them at the login screen.

```
yum groupinstall "KDE Software Compilation"
```

```
yum groupinstall "GNOME Desktop Environment"
```